# Continuity of the composition of operator-valued continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $M$ be a metric space, $E_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $f_i:M\to\mathfrak L(E_i,E_{i+1}$.

> If $x\in M$ and $f_i$ is continuous at $x$, can we show that $f_2f_1$ is continuous at $x$?

We should be able to prove the claim directly from the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$-definition of continuity. However, the claim would be way more easier follow if we would be able to show that $$\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2)\times\mathfrak L(E_2,E_3)\to\mathfrak L(E_1,E_3)\;,\;\;\;(A,B)\mapsto BA\tag1$$ is continuous. But I'm not sure if this is really the case? Do we need to assume that $E_3$ (or $E_2$) is finite-dimensional?

Comment: You might want to prove for yourself (it is also widely available in the literature) that if $E, F$ and $ G$ are normed spaces then a bilinear map $\mu: E\times F\to G$ is continuous if and only if there is a nonnegative constant $c$ such that $\Vert\mu(x,y)\Vert \leq c\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$, for all $x$ in $E$ and $y$ in $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is triangle inequality: Let $x_n \to x$. $$\|f_2(x_n)f_1(x_n)-f_2(x)f_1(x)\|$$ $$=\|f_2(x_n)f_1(x_n)-f_2(x_n)f_1(x)$$ $$+f_2(x_n)f_1(x)-f_2(x)f_1(x)\|$$ $$ \leq \|f_2(x_n)\| \|f_1(x_n)-f_1(x)\|$$ $$+\|f_2(x_n)-f_2(x)\|\|f_1(x)\| .$$ Now just note that $ \|f_2(x_n)\| $ is bounded.

The same type of  argument shows that $(A,B) \to AB$ is continuous for the operator norm. No need for finite dimensionality.